# How to get optimal cutoff values for two variables with linear programming

Tags: r, linear-programming, threshold, simplex

I am trying to use the simplex algorithm to determine the optimal values of two variables to target most appealing persons with a marketing campaign. The variables are individual treatment effects (as an output from a predictive model) and expenditures per person. Now I want to identify the optimal levels of these variables to maximize expenditures while securing that we only target the persons where the treatment has a high positive effect. I further have the constraint of targeting only 20% of people from the whole data. I believe that linear programming helps me achieve this.

To get the values for the objective function, I am simply using the mean values per variable and follow a maximization objective. I am however stuck with the constraint function as I don't know how to set it up given my requirement. Apparently, treatm_score + expenditures < [20% of observations] works conceptually, but from a programming view, I am mixing up values with quantities I think. It seems that I need at least one constraint to use linear programming to get the cutoff values (if I could get the cutoff values without the need for a constraint, I would also be happy). I am looking for making a statement such as "As a product seller, I maximize my expected sales to z if I target people with an individual treatment effect of at least x and expenditures of at least y".

**My questions are:** 
1) Can you help me determine the cutoff values? 
2) Is there maybe a better way to achieve the goal?

Let's use the following code to generate the data

```
treatm_score <- rnorm(1000, 0.1, 0.02)
hist(treatm_score)

isZero = rbinom(n=1000, size=1, prob=0.95)
expenditures = ifelse(isZero==1, 0, rlnorm(sum(isZero==0), meanlog=1, sdlog=2))
hist(expenditures); table(expenditures)
length(expenditures[expenditures>0]) / length(expenditures) *100 # 5% of people with expenditures

mean_treatm_score <- mean(treatm_score)
mean_expenditures <- mean(expenditures)
```

We see that the distributions of the variables are very different and only some persons actually spend money in the past (about 5% from the whole, which is realistic).

If I follow https://en.proft.me/2015/09/23/classical-simplex-method-and-calc-r/, I need to load the linprog package and tried the following (here is where I fail):

```
install.packages("linprog"); library("linprog")

c = c(mean(treatm_score), mean(expenditures)) # objective function
max_quant = 0.2*length(expenditures) # constraint: only 20% of all observations
b = c(max_quant)
res = solveLP(c, b, maximum=TRUE) # does not work
```

Your help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: I would suggest to first develop a mathematical model before even looking at code.

Comment: Dear @ErwinKalvelagen, thanks for your response. Could you specify how I can do this?

Comment: This can be done on a piece of paper. Once the mathematical model is more or less settled, implementing it in code is often much easier.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to develop such a mathematical model. Can you help how I can proceed with it?